# How Do I install debian packages onto mac-osx-mojave (10.14)

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, osx

How Do I install debian packages onto mac-osx-mojave (10.14)

Comment: What Linux commands? You can't install `apt-get` on macOS, that's a tool for installing Debian packages, it would be useless on macOS. Please [edit] your question and explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: how do I edit the question

Comment: You edit the question by pressing the [edit] link under it.

Comment: like that? mabey that is more clear

Comment: You're using macOS, but you want to install Debian packages onto it? That doesn't really make much sense. You might want to tell us what software you need on your macOS and someone might help you out with installing it on macOS. But Debian packages are meant to be used on Linux.

Comment: I found "/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"" what is that

Comment: but i thaught mac os was linux

Comment: No, macOS is not Linux.

Comment: the why would it be in unix and why are most of the commands the same

Comment: who is downvoting my question

Comment: Both macOS and Linux are Unix-like operating systems, but they are, beneath the surface, fundamentally different.  The command line _looks_ and behaves the same, because there is a standard for how a Unix system should behave (the standard is called ["POSIX"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/)).  macOS and Debian are sufficiently different "under the hood" to be incompatible when it comes to running many types of software, and in particular, you can't install Debian packages on macOS, or macOS packages (Homebrew packages) on Debian.

Comment: See also [What makes OSX programs not runnable on Linux?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/3322) for a technical discussion about why macOS programs can't be run on Linux. There are also other questions on this site that discusses compatibility between macOS and Linux, e.g. [Binary compatibility between Mac OS X and Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/7874)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install Debian packages on macOS.

You can however use something like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and install 3rd-party software that way instead.  Homebrew is a widely used package manager on macOS systems and provides a wide variety of packages.  Note though that the package names may be different from those on Debian and that there's no guarantee that a piece of software that you find on Debian exists in Homebrew for macOS.

See also the [Homebrew Documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/).

Comment: what is that? what is homebrew

Comment: @LaithStriegher I did provide a link. Click it and it will take you to the [Homebrew homepage](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: ok i will ckeck it

Comment: I found "/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"" what is that

Comment: @LaithStriegher That is the command that installs Homebrew, i.e. it installs the `brew` command that you later use to actually install packages.

Comment: so how do I install debian pakages with it

Comment: @LaithStriegher You can't install Debian packages on macOS. You can install Homebrew packages with the `brew` command (e.g. `brew install vim` or whatever you want to install).

Comment: I now understand

Comment: Technically, nothing prevents Debian packages to target a Darwin (macOS) system when they are being built, all they would need is build those packages from the corresponding toolchains instead of native linux ones.
This would not be trivial but this is far from impossible.
The Nix package manager works just fine on macOS.

Comment: @LaurentGiroud That is correct. Packaging tools are generally portable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install Debian packages compiled for **another architecture or operating system** than macOS on a Mac.

**However**, you can install apt and Debian packages compiled for macOS on a Mac by using the Fink project.
.
Quoting from their website (https://www.finkproject.org):

> The Fink project wants to bring the full world of Unix Open Source software to Darwin and Mac OS X. We modify Unix software so that it compiles and runs on Mac OS X ("port" it) and make it available for download as a coherent distribution. Fink uses Debian tools like dpkg and apt-get to provide powerful binary package management. You can choose whether you want to download precompiled binary packages or build everything from source.